# MongoDB - sorting by value in key-value arrays

Tags: json, mongodb, sorting

I have this data structure

```
{
  "_id": "123456789abc",
  ...
  "information": [
    {
      "key": "email",
      "value": "test@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "key": "company",
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "key": "registrationDate",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2023-11-10T20:00:49.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "expiryDate",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2024-11-10T20:02:11.000Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to sort the results of a query by values within the 'information.key' field

for example:

```
information.key = email: information.value 1
information.key = registrationDate: information.value -1
```

How can i do this?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Will the `key` in each object under `information` always be unique? PS. If you can control the schema, the `information` should have directly been an object instead of a list of objects. ie `"information": {"email": "test@abc.com", "company": "ABC", "registrationDate": {"$date": "2023-11-10T20:00:49.000Z"}, "expiryDate": {"$date": "2024-11-10T20:02:11.000Z"} }` In Mongo/NoSQL, de-normalised is better.

Comment: no they are not unique, only _id is unique

Comment: So if "email" or "registrationDate" occur multiple times in "information", then which one should be used? First occurrence, Last? Ascending/Descending for repeated + Ascending/Descending on those fields?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that unless you expect multiple users to have the same email, that's already _unique_ (if verified accounts), so just doing a sort on email would then not require a second level sort on registration date.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately the same email is repeated several times.. the sorting is by "email": 1, "registrationDate":-1

Comment: I meant, _"Will the `key` in each object under `information` always be unique?"_ As in, is it possible to have an entry with two `email` items like `{ "_id": "fedbca654321", "information": [ {"key": "email", "value": "atest1@abc.com"}, {"key": "email", "value": "ztest99@abc.com"}, {"key": "company", ...} }`? Or even two registration dates in `information`. If it's not possible, then [ray's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524495/1431750) is what you need. Otherwise, you need a way to select one email entry over the other. Ray's solution will select the last occurrence of repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array into an object with `$arrayToObject` then sort on the newly created object's fields.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "infoObject": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$information",
            "as": "i",
            "in": {
              k: "$$i.key",
              v: "$$i.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "infoObject.email": 1,
      "infoObject.registrationDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "infoObject"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l2086qUZItD)

Comment: I think this is the right solution but [OP needs to clarify the behaviour they want if keys within `information` are repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522433/mongodb-sorting-by-value-in-key-value-arrays#comment136667965_77522433). Since that affects the first `arrayToObject` step. Using your solution minus `unset` (for clarity), it would pick the latter key when there are repetitions. [Mongo Playground with repeated keys in `info`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dIN_mBo6TvC).